# Flexible replace substring - Scheme

Tags: string, replace, scheme, substring

Is there, in Scheme, a good way to replace a substring of a string with another string, the length of which could vary? I am looking for something similar to this:

```
(replace-all string pattern replacement)
(replace-all "slig slog slag" "g" "ggish")
    => "sliggish sloggish slaggish"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can **roll your own**. It's not very efficient but it will do the work on small strings. (I wouldn't use it on string lengths above a million chars)

Make `(prefix? src prefix)` such that i evaluates to #t if the beginning of the list `src` is the same as `prefix`.

Make `(append-reverse rev-head tail)` such that `(append-reverse '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) ; ==> (3 2 1 4 5 6)`. This could easily be done with `foldl` or it's a standard procedure in [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#append-reverse)

Then `(replace-all haystack needle replacement)` is quite simple:

```scm
(define (replace-all haystack needle replacement)    
  ;; most of the processing works on lists 
  ;; of char, not strings.
  (let ((haystack (string->list haystack))
        (needle (string->list needle))
        (replacement (string->list replacement))
        (needle-len (string-length needle)))
    (let loop ((haystack haystack) (acc '()))
      (cond ((null? haystack)
             (list->string (reverse acc)))
            ((prefix? haystack needle)
             (loop (list-tail haystack needle-len)
                   (reverse-append replacement acc)))
            (else
             (loop (cdr haystack) (cons (car haystack) acc)))))))

(replace-all "The cat looks like a cat." "cat" "dog")
; ==> "The dog looks like a dog."
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, take a look at the documentation of your Scheme interpreter to find a suitable procedure. For instance, in Racket we have [`string-replace`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fstring..rkt%29._string-replace%29%29) which works like this:

```
(string-replace "slig slog slag" "g" "ggish")
=> "sliggish sloggish slaggish"
```